# How to replace a character in a string with NULL in ANSI C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, ansi-c

I want to replace all 'a' characters from a string in ANSI C. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sos(char *dst){
    while(*dst){
        if(*dst == 'a')
        *dst = '\0';
        dst++;
        }
}


int main(void){
    char str[20] = "pasternak";
    sos(str);
    printf("str2 = %s \n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, result is:

```
str2 = p
```

But it should be

```
str2 = psternk
```

It works fine with other characters like 'b' etc. I tried to assign NULL to *dst, but I got error during compile.
How can I remove 'a' characters now?

Comment: These are zero-terminated strings. Zero marks end of the string.

Comment: I see, then how can I remove specific characters?

Comment: Replacing a character with null makes that the new end of the string.  To remove characters you must actually copy the string.  If you're clever you can copy it to itself, a character at a time, skipping the characters you want to omit.  (In fact, I'm guessing this is homework and that's what you're supposed to figure out -- on your own, without someone else coding it for you.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`'\0'` is how the C language tools recognize the end of the string. In order to actually remove a character, you'll need to shift all of the subsequent characters forward.

```
void sos(char *dst) {
  int offset = 0;
  do {
    while (dst[offset] == 'a') ++offset;
    *dst = dst[offset];
  } while (*dst++);
}
```

Comment: @AliGH: there you go, someone went and did your homework for you. You learned a useful skill today!

Comment: I think that 'machine' is not the right term, but the C string routines instead of.

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings are **zero-terminated**, it means that when there's a `'\0'` in the string it is the **end of the string**.

So what you're doing is spliting the string in 3 different ones:

```
p
stern
k
```

If you want to delete the `a` you must move all the characters after the `a` one position.

Answer (score 1):

What printf does is: read bytes until a `'\0'` is found.

You transformed `"pasternak"` to `"p\0astern\0k"`, so printf prints `p`.

This convention is used on the string functions of the stdlib so that you don't have to pass string length as an argument.

This is why it is said that in C strings are null terminated: it is just a convention followed by the C stdlib.

The downside, as you discovered, is that strings cannot contain `\0`.

If you really want to print a given number of bytes, use something like `fwrite`, which counts the number of bytes to be printed, so it can print a `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers previously provided are perfect to explain why your code does not work. But you can try to use strtok to split the string based on the 'a' characters, to then join the parts together or simply print them appart. Check this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm